# How to connect to odoo from distance

Tags: odoo, windows-server-2012-r2, odoo-11, erp

I'm setting up a new server 2012 R2, and want to be connected to it remotely using an IP address or a domain name.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read your modem's/gateway's manual and learn how to forward ports
2. Forward ports 8069 and 8072 to your windows server
3. Visit https://www.whatismyip.com/ or any other service that tells you your public IP address
4. Open your browser and go to `http://<your_public_IP_address>:8069`

Comment: Great! Glad to help. If this solved your question, could you please select this answer as correct?